# Adapteva/ Parallela Chip

Tags: parallel-processing, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Does anyone know if this chip is 32-bit or 64-bit? I would like to know before I decide to purchase one of these boards for development.

Comment: Why did you vote my question down? I have looked through the manual before, and it does not explicitly say which architecture the processor is. One part of it states, "A superscalar, floating-point RISC CPU in each mesh node that can execute two floating 
point operations and a 64-bit memory load operation on every clock cycle." Another part says, "The architecture employs a flat 
32-bit memory map and supports up to 4096 individual mesh nodes." This is why I am confused and asked my question.

Comment: It is clearly written that registers are 32-bit. The x86 architecture supports 80-bit loads to the FPU and 256-bit loads to the AVX engine - does that make it an 80-bit or 256-bit architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Microprocessor Report on Adapteva](http://www.adapteva.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/adapteva_mpr.pdf) (PDF):

> The design also eschews memory management of any kind, implementing a
>   flat 32-bit memory space without any protection

and also

> The instruction set supports load and store double instructions that
>   access two consecutive 32-bit registers, taking advantage of the
>   64-bit path from the SRAM to the register file.

So it sounds like a 32-bit computer than can do some 64-bit operations.